# BigQuery: Specify a condition in count()

Tags: google-bigquery

i have a session table which has a userId and a nested record for visited homepage (string) and a timestamp for each visit in one session. Basically a 1:m relationship in one row:

```
                     UserId|SessionEndTime|page1|timestamp1|
                                          |page2|timestamp2|
                                          |page1|timestamp3|
```

What i want to know is how can i get all userId who have visited my page 6x in the last 6 months and they should have visited pages (with a name like '%astring%') at least 2 times.

This is my approach but how can i bring the like condition into a count()?:

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(UserId) AS visitCounter FROM [oxidation.TestVisits]
WHERE SessionEndTime >= TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),-6,"MONTH"))
      AND LastUserId != 'none'
GROUP BY 1
HAVING visitCounter>=6
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `SUM(page LIKE '%astring%') AS pageCounter` to your query

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(UserId) AS visitCounter, 
  SUM(page LIKE '%astring%') AS pageCounter
FROM [oxidation.TestVisits]
WHERE SessionEndTime >= TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),-6,"MONTH"))
      AND LastUserId != 'none'
GROUP BY 1
HAVING visitCounter>=6
AND pageCounter >= 2
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```